# Manage ViewState with ConfirmationDialog using RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

```
override fun submitIntent(): Observable<Triple<Long, Long, String>> {



        AlertOP.showPasswordVerificationDialog(requireContext(), object : GeneralDialogListener{
            override fun onPositiveClick() {

            }

            override fun onNegativeClick() {

            }
        })

        return binding.btnShareData.clicks().map {

            binding.data?.let {
                KeyboardOp.hide(requireActivity(), binding.etDataVolume)

                Triple(selectedCreditAccountID, selectedBundleCreditID, it.dataVolume)
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is a problem, I want to trigger this

```
return binding.btnShareData.clicks().map {

            binding.data?.let {
                KeyboardOp.hide(requireActivity(), binding.etDataVolume)

                Triple(selectedCreditAccountID, selectedBundleCreditID, it.dataVolume)
            }
        }
```

only when `onPositiveClick` is pressed using `RxJava`. The `AlertOP.showPasswordVerificationDialog(...` is a confirmation dialog. Please help, and please ignore if have asked this question in a poor way. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some search I was able to solve the issue by using `PublishSubject` of `RxJava`
Here is a look to my updated code

```
private val verifyPasswordSubmitEventBridge = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

... 

override fun submitIntent(): Observable<Triple<Long, Long, String>> {
        binding.btnShareData.setOnClickListener {

            AlertOP.showPasswordVerificationDialog(
                requireContext(),
                object : GeneralDialogListener {
                    override fun onPositiveClick() {
                        verifyPasswordSubmitEventBridge.onNext(true)
                    }

                    override fun onNegativeClick() {
                        verifyPasswordSubmitEventBridge.onNext(false)
                    }
                })
        }
        return verifyPasswordSubmitEventBridge.filter { it }.map {
            binding.data?.let {
                KeyboardOp.hide(requireActivity(), binding.etDataVolume)

                Triple(selectedCreditAccountID, selectedBundleCreditID, it.dataVolume)
            }

        }
    }
```

and now I'm able to achieve which was required, on submitIntent `ViewState` I can now show a confirmation `dialog` before proceeding forward to the `API` call using `RxJava`